# Formula to autofill value from a list on a separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In a Google Sheets workbook, I have a sheet named **`Tax Codes and Rates`** containing a tax table with the following 4 columns: **`County`** ,  **`Municipality or County`** ,  **`Location Code`** ,  **`Rate`**

#### Sample Lookup Data

**<sup>`Sheet: 'Tax Codes and Rates'`</sup>**

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **County** | **Municipality or County** | **Location Code** | **Rate** |
| **2** | Bernalillo | Santolina TID District 20 | 02-640 | 6.31% |
| **3** | Bernalillo | Upper Petroglyphs TID District 1 | 02-607 | 6.31% |
| **4** | Catron | Reserve | 28-130 | 7.88% |
| **5** | Curry | Remainder of County | **`05-005`** | **`6.00%`** |
| **6** | Eddy | Artesia | 03-205 | 7.77% |
| **7** | Eddy | Carlsbad | 03-106 | 7.52% |
| **8 - ?** | ... | ... *etc.* | ... | ... |

In a separate sheet named **`DA Template`**, I want a formula that takes a **`Location Code`** as input and returns the **`Rate`** from the matching row in the **`Tax Codes and Rates`** sheet.

##### Sample Results

**<sup>`Sheet: 'DA Template'`</sup>**

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Lookup Value** <sup>( Location Code )</sup> | **Formula Result** <sup>( Rate )</sup> |
| **2** | **`05-005`** | **`6.00%`** |
| **3** | 02-607 | 6.31% |
| **4** | 03-106 | 7.52% |

Using the sample tables above,

1. Lookup value **`05-005`** located in **`'DA Template'!A2`** matches **`'Tax Codes and Rates'!C5'`**
2. Formula in **`'DA Template'!B2`** returns **`6.00%`** the value from **`Rate`** in the same row: **`'Tax Codes and Rates'!D5'`**

What formula would automatically return the **`Rate`** based on the **`Location Code`**?

[Sample Google Sheets Workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x4GhIv4ptDkM-IpfdtLH2cFtfKk5gzYTYo4ETKhY68Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect use case for the `VLOOKUP` function.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, 'Tax Codes and Rates'!C2:D35, 2, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167347) works well.  I show a couple of alternatives below as well as **VLOOKUP Single-Formula** which extends the approach in the [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167347) to calculate the results for multiple rows.

##### FILTER

```
=FILTER('Tax Codes and Rates'!D$2:D$35,
   'Tax Codes and Rates'!C$2:C$35=A2)
```

##### INDEX and MATCH

```
=INDEX('Tax Codes and Rates'!D$2:D$35,
   MATCH(A2, 'Tax Codes and Rates'!C$2:C$35, 0))
```

### VLOOKUP Single-Formula

VLOOKUP in the [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167347) is well-suited to be extended  using the ARRAYFORMULA function so that it returns results for multiple rows using a single formula.

If your lookup values are in `A2:A10` you would use a single formula in `B2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   VLOOKUP(A2:A10, 'Tax Codes and Rates'!C2:D35, 2, 0))
```